# how to store javascript value in php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code.

It's working fine for first var but its showing undefined variable for second.

How I suppose to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
  var p1 = "success";
  var time = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;
</script>


<body>
  <div id="time">04:00</div>
  <?php
     echo "<script>document.writeln(p1);</script>";
     echo $timevalue = "<script>document.writeln(time);</script>";
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to inverse the order

```
 <div id="time">04:00</div>

 <script>
    var p1 = "success";
    var time = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;
 </script>  

 <?php
    echo "<script>document.writeln(p1);</script>";
    echo $timevalue = "<script>document.writeln(time);</script>";
  ?>
```